# Spring caching / spring repository, evict multiple keys

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-cache

I have two methods to fetch an entity with two different parameters. I also have a save method that uses one of those parameters. How can I evict the entity from the cache under both fetch keys? e.g. see below:

```
@Cacheable  
public User getByUsername(String username);

@Cacheable  
public User getByEmail(String email);


@CacheEvict(key="#entity.username")
User save(User entity);
```

In the above, a call to getByEmail will return stale date.

Answer (score 14):

There are several options, of course, but as usual, *Spring* has your back.

The easiest and most simple approach is to leverage Spring's `@Caching` annotation on your `save` method, like so...

```
@Caching(evict = {
  @CacheEvict(cacheNames = "Users", key="#user.name"),
  @CacheEvict(cacheNames = "Users", key="#user.email")
})
User save(User user);
```

For your reference, I created an example test class demonstrating this working [here](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/cache/MultiCacheEvictionWithGemFireIntegrationTest.java).

You will notice I imitated your example above using *Spring's* Cache Abstraction annotations on my [UserRepository](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/cache/MultiCacheEvictionWithGemFireIntegrationTest.java#L397-L410).  In this case, my repo is backed by *Pivotal GemFire*, but any data store will work.  I use a `ConcurrentMap` as my caching provider, using Spring's [ConcurrentMapCacheManager](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/cache/MultiCacheEvictionWithGemFireIntegrationTest.java#L193-L206), but of course, any caching provider will do.

My [test case](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-gemfire-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/org/spring/cache/MultiCacheEvictionWithGemFireIntegrationTest.java#L149-L186) proceeds to save a **new** `User`, ensuring that the user is stored by not yet cached.  The test then proceeds to exercise the query methods (`findByName`, `findByEmail`) ensuring that the user entity is cached appropriately in each case.  I then remove the entity from the underlying data store and ensure that the entity is still cached.  And finally, the moment of truth, I modify the entity, re-save the entity, asserting that the entity is stored by that **all** entries have been "evicted" from the cache.

You could also try, as another optimization, to combine the `@CachePut` annotation with the 2 `@CacheEvict` annotations in this case, which could restore the cache based on the new, updated entity, something like...

```
@Caching(
  evict = {
    @CacheEvict(cacheNames = "Users", key="#a0.name", beforeInvocation = true),
    @CacheEvict(cacheNames = "Users", key="#a0.email", beforeInvocation = true)
  },
  put = {
    @CachePut(cacheNames = "Users", key="#result.name"),
    @CachePut(cacheNames = "Users", key="#result.email")
  }
)
User save(User user);
```

NOTE: notice the user of the `beforeInvocation` attribute on the `@CacheEvict` annotations along with the `@CachePuts`

However, you may prefer that the entity be lazily added to the cache based on need.

Although, you would presume the entity is being frequently accessed/used since the `save` method on your repo was just called, and therefore rely on your underlying data store (such as GemFire) to set additional eviction (based on overflow)/expiration (based on LRU) settings, thereby better managing your system resources (e.g. memory) while still maintaining optimal application performance.

Food for thought.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this looks good. Question: what is the difference between #a0, #a1, ..., and #p0, p1,..., and using the method parameter var name 'user'. (Actually, I can't seem to get the parameter name to work in the SpEL, I get an error: "property field username cannot be found on null", null being the object).

Comment: Another thought: while it does seem to make sense to use the #result.name and result.email to prepopulate the cache, I am concerned about concurrency issues using the beforeInvocation = true. It might be safer to simply have  @CachePut(key="#a0.name"), etc. i.e. the impact & likelihood of save() implementations actually changing the values vs. impact & likelihood of a concurrency issue.

Comment: And another question: in the above example, the email property may or may not be null. This will not work with some cache implementation (e.g. concurrentHashMap). I wish there was a parameter called 'ignoreNullKeys' that I can set to false, which in turn does not execute the calls to 'doEvict' or 'put' on keys with null values.

Comment: Addressing your questions in order... the #a<number> is the method parameter arguments in the order declared (as if passed in an array and the number being the index).  This convention is necessary if you are not compiling with debug information.

Comment: Concerning the beforeInvocation=true... certainly there are concurrency issues to think of in a multi-threaded environment to be sure, but the real downside is pre-evicting the entries before you know whether save is going to be successful or not.  Where as, the @CachePut only happens on a a successful completion of the invoked method.

Comment: Finally, concerning the ConcurrentMapCacheManager, well, yet again, Spring has your back, ;-)  See... http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/concurrent/ConcurrentMapCacheManager.html#setAllowNullValues-boolean-

Comment: I don't understand the phrase "Spring has your back", and so Google too.